# Sorting multidimensional array with exceptions

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have a file which contains time and some data. I need to sort the array by its time, however there are two snags: if the time is 23:59:59:999 or Null, 
it needs to stay where it is in relation to everything else. I've taken in the file and placed it in an array of arrays.

For example:

```
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

should become:

```
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

What I currently have done is sort them into separate "blocks" (time, Null times etc) so that when I dump the array of data it looks like:

```
(
    [
        [
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.001",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.002",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.005",
          "data2",
        ],
    ],
    [
        [ 
          "data1",
          "Null",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "Null",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "Null",
          "data2",
        ],
    ],
    [
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.006",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.007",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.008",
          "data2",
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
          "data1",
          "23:59:59:999",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "23:59:59:999",
          "data2",
        ],
    ],
    [
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.003",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.004",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.010",
          "data2",
        ],
        [ 
          "data1",
          "10:25:34.011",
          "data2",
        ],
    ]
)
```

My idea is to find the maximum value from the "first" block and ignore the "Null" and "23:59:59.999" blocks, and push any values in the remaining block that is larger than the maximum value of the "first" block.

I'm having difficulty moving the times between the separate blocks and to then sort it, and was wondering if anyone had any advise on how to do this (or if there is a better way of 
sorting it from the structure I've got so far) ?

Comment: An example of what you're doing so far will get you better answers.

Comment: Is it possible for the input to look like, say, `2, Null, 1` (where I've used simple integers instead of timestamps for brevity), and if yes, where should the null entry end up after sorting? And what about, say, `1, Null, 4, 2, 3`?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean @IlmariKaronen, in my example above the `Null` is the timestamp. And the null entry should not move from where it is (or be shifted down if a timestamp is shifted up).

Comment: I was just listing the values for the column that is being used to sort the records, and ignoring the (apparently irrelevant) data columns. What I was trying to ask is, if you had an input sequence like `2, 3, 1` and sorted it, you would end up with `1, 2, 3`. So what about `2, Null, 1`: would you expect `1, 2, Null`, `Null, 1, 2`, or perhaps `1, Null, 2`?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I would expect `1, 2, Null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you cannot sort the original data structure. You need to transform it so that the rows whose relative positions you want to preserve are attached to the preceding elements.

Here's the updated version that is a bit better than the first implementation I posted (see edit history if curious):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = [ [ split ' ', scalar <DATA> ] ];

while (my $row = <DATA>) {
    next unless $row =~ /\S/;
    my @x = split ' ', $row;
    if (($x[1] eq 'Null') or ($x[1] eq '23:59:59:999')) {
        push @{ $data[-1] }, \@x;
        next;
    }
    push @data, [ \@x ];
}

@data = map @$_, sort { $a->[0][1] cmp $b->[0][1] } @data;

print "@$_\n" for @data;

__DATA__
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

Output:

```
data1 10:25:34.001 data2
data1 10:25:34.002 data2
data1 10:25:34.003 data2
data1 10:25:34.004 data2
data1 10:25:34.005 data2
data1 Null data2
data1 Null data2
data1 Null data2
data1 10:25:34.006 data2
data1 10:25:34.007 data2
data1 10:25:34.008 data2
data1 23:59:59:999 data2
data1 23:59:59:999 data2
data1 10:25:34.010 data2
data1 10:25:34.011 data2
```

This does assume that the first line of data is not a `Null` or midnight event. You can use a sentry element if the first row of the data may contain a `Null` or midnight event:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = [ [ undef, undef, undef ] ];

while (my $row = <DATA>) {
    next unless $row =~ /\S/;
    my @x = split ' ', $row;
    if (($x[1] eq 'Null') or ($x[1] eq '23:59:59:999')) {
        push @{ $data[-1] }, \@x;
        next;
    }
    push @data, [ \@x ];
}

@data = map @$_, sort {
    $a->[0][1] or return -1;
    $b->[0][1] or return  1;
    $a->[0][1] cmp $b->[0][1]
} @data;

shift @data;
print "@$_\n" for @data;
```

We make sure the sentry element sorts before any other element, and then remove it before doing anything further with the data.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question, can you please explain what this line does? `push @{ $data[-1] }, \@x;`

Comment: `$data[-1]` would be an array reference (second dimension of the array). This is inserting an extra value - a reference to `@x` into it.

Comment: @Sobrique Thanks. OP: Instead of storing each row in an anonymous array, I am storing it in an anonymous array of anonymous arrays. If a row has any `Null` or midnight successors, they are stored alongside it, but rows are only sorted according to non-`Null` non-midnight criteria. `$data[-1]` is the ref to last insert anonymous array of anonymous arrays. That line pushes a `Null` or midnight row at the end of that anon array thereby "attaching" `Null` and midnight rows to the immediately preceding row.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the problem here is - when you are sorting something, you can't really have 'exceptions' - each element must be compared to each other element, and a relative position established.

The best you could perhaps do is a custom sort function, that compared the values, and returned `0` if a `null` element was encountered... but that wouldn't necessarily have the right result, because sorting *assumes* positioning is logically consistent - and yours won't be, because you may need to 'skip' some chunks in the middle.

So I would approach it like this:

- Keep your original list.
- Create a 'new' list, of things to be sorted.
- sort the new list.
- iterate the original list, and print the 'sticky' value if present, and the next element of the sorted list if it isn't.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @list_of_stuff = map { [split] } <DATA>;
my @list_to_sort =
    grep { $_->[1] ne 'Null'
      and  $_->[1] ne '23:59:59:999' }
    @list_of_stuff;

my @sorted = sort { $b->[1] cmp $a->[1] } @list_to_sort;

foreach my $row (@list_of_stuff) {
    if (   $row->[1] eq "Null"
        or $row->[1] eq '23:59:59:999' )
    {
        print join( "\t", @$row );
    }
    else {
        print join( "\t", @{ pop @sorted } );
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

This produces:

```
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   Null    data2
data1   Null    data2
data1   Null    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

Note - sorting on your timestamps is stringwise - that works in this scenario, but I'd normally suggest converting to timestamps. That doesn't work as well given that 'unix time' doesn't support milliseconds, and so I have left it to one side.

OK, second attempt now I've realised that you're not so much looking to make exceptions, as 'anchor' invalid values to the parent values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $last;
my @list_to_sort;
#iterate input data
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    #extract this row into an anonymous array. 
    my $stuff = [split];

    #check if it's 'valid' in it's own right. 
    if (   $stuff->[1] eq 'Null'
        or $stuff->[1] eq '23:59:59:999' )
    {
        #if it isn't, 'tag on' to the last element we've seen.
        #NB - will error if there's no valid 'first' row. 
        push( @$last, $stuff );
    }
    else {
        #insert into 'list_to_sort
        my $thing = [ $stuff->[1], $stuff ];
        push( @list_to_sort, $thing );
        #make a note of the last array ref to insert next stuff into. 
        $last = $thing;
    }

}

print Dumper \@list_to_sort;

my @sorted = sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @list_to_sort;

print Dumper \@sorted;

foreach my $blob (@sorted) {
    foreach my $line (@$blob) {
        #because we're 'keying' this element,
        #we don't actually need to print the 'key'. 
        next unless ref $line;
        print join( "\t", @$line ), "\n";
    }
}


__DATA__
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   Null            data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

What this does is cycle through the list, and if the element is 'valid' insert it into the to_sort list. And if it isn't, attach it to the last valid.

I'm unsure what it *should* do if your list doesn't have a valid first element though - it would break in that scenario.

Each element looks like:

```
      [
        '10:25:34.008',
        [
          'data1',
          '10:25:34.008',
          'data2'
        ],
        [
          'data1',
          '23:59:59:999',
          'data2'
        ],
        [
          'data1',
          '23:59:59:999',
          'data2'
        ]
      ],
```

That's a *bit* like a hash - I didn't use one, because whilst your keys are unique I am assuming they don't have to be.

This gives results of:

```
data1   10:25:34.001    data2
data1   10:25:34.002    data2
data1   10:25:34.003    data2
data1   10:25:34.004    data2
data1   10:25:34.005    data2
data1   Null    data2
data1   Null    data2
data1   Null    data2
data1   10:25:34.006    data2
data1   10:25:34.007    data2
data1   10:25:34.008    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   23:59:59:999    data2
data1   10:25:34.010    data2
data1   10:25:34.011    data2
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. Yes. I'm trying to ensure 'sorting with exclusions' but it isn't really, is it? It's 'anchoring' "nulls" next to "last valid". I'll have another bash at it.